# How to link one given Image field to a specific view?

Tags: 7, navigation, media

I would like to link an **Image** field to a specific view (created with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)) in a given *view mode*, under *"Manage fields"* tab, making this opportunity available **only within a given content type and only one specific field**.

I could also "hack" it into a given `theme_image_...` function, but I think it would be nicer to make it easily modifiable via the admin interface like this:

[image]

Maybe this could easily be done with a given or a custom module, but I don't know what would be a nice solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

1. On the content type hide the image from the display as you will show it with as an EVA field.
2. Using Views EVA attach the image to the content type so that the image is visible again, don't forget to check the views arguments to that the right images is shown in the node.
3. Re-write the image to be display as a link and there you can put the path to the view. Here you can also play with the image formatter as well.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good idea. I've never used EVA, so can you please be more specific? Another important question: doesn't it consume too much resources for this task to attach a view for a simple linking? Until then, +1 for your answer. :)

Comment: Like using any other view you can always play with the view cache system. I have use EVA field for all the content type fields in some projects and I have never had a performance issue. BTW you can provably accomplish the same with panels, display suite or context modules, but since chances are you already have views in your project I like to keep the module count low.